# Not able to clone a git repo in Docker Quickstart Terminal - could not create work tree dir 'node-bulletin-board': Permission denied

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile, containers

I am trying to get started with Docker and following official documentation, in which there is a [step](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#git) where we need to clone a git repo.

[image: Set up Git Repo]

> I got stuck at this [step](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#git).
>   [image]

I cloned the same repo in another location (D:\path_to_file_loaction) using git bash, but not able to navigate to that location in the Docker Quickstart Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Check first your current working directory when you are typing git clone:

```
pwd
```

If that returns, for instance, /, that would be owned by root instead of your account.

Try instead:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/dockersamples/node-bulletin-board
```